# Parsing Makefile list var

Tags: string, bash, shell, parsing, makefile

Thank You in advance. 
I have a list where each entry is a word.
For example:  Here is the command

```
'tvc := $(shell jpl-tcs.sh --check_tool_versions --pcf $(PCF))'
```

Here is the output:
    `@N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found par directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/par @N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found bit directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/bit @N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found log directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/logs @N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found cores directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/cores @N: tcs_init_pkg::check_xilinx_env_var: XILINX env var is set to: /data/opt/Xilinx/13.2/ISE_DS/ISE @N: jpl-tcs.sh: Checking tool versions @N: tcs_check_versions.py: tool_version.txt found @N: tcs_check_versions.py: Found tool_version.txt in xilinx @N: tcs_check_versions.py: Tool version check : Completed. ---> Local tool versions match tool_version.txt! @N: jpl-tcs.sh: Passed Tool Check @N: jpl-tcs.sh: Using default Xilinx command-line options file: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/tcs_defaults/tcs_xcl_tools.sh`

I want to format the output to the console or screen like this.

```
@N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found par directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/par 
@N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found bit directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/bit 
@N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found log directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/logs 
@N: tcs_init_pkg::tcs_build_dirs: Found cores directory: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/examples/build/cntr/xilinx/cores 
@N: tcs_init_pkg::check_xilinx_env_var: XILINX env var is set to: /data/opt/Xilinx/13.2/ISE_DS/ISE 
@N: jpl-tcs.sh: Checking tool versions 
@N: tcs_check_versions.py: tool_version.txt found 
@N: tcs_check_versions.py: Found tool_version.txt in xilinx 
@N: tcs_check_versions.py: Tool version check : Completed. ---> Local tool versions match tool_version.txt! 
@N: jpl-tcs.sh: Passed Tool Check 
@N: jpl-tcs.sh: Using default Xilinx command-line options file: /data/home/nbrummel/jpl-tcs/tcs_defaults/tcs_xcl_tools.sh`
```

Where the new print out would always start with the '@' character.  I have gotten it to print out one word on each line but that is not what I want.  Any help would be great. Also, this can not be in a recipe.

if I run `jpl-tcs.sh ...` I get the formatted output above. If i run the same command in Make with `tvc:=$(shell jpl-tcs.sh ...)` and `$(info $(tvc))` then I get the garbed output where the newline characters are omitted. I want it to display like it does in the shell but when I call it in make. How do I do that?

Comment: Are the apostraphes part of the input line, ` at beginning and end? can you remove it if not used

Comment: Where does that list come from? (And how did the `@N`s get into it?) I have the feeling that this is an X-Y problem...

Comment: The @N's are from output or status updates to the terminal. I need them to print to screen but they are not via Make.

Comment: What do you mean by "output or status updates to the terminal"? Do you mean that your jpl-tcs.sh script is somehow inserting them?

Comment: They are printed to the terminal to inform the user.  It works fine in shell and if it is placed in a target it works fine as well.  I want to run the script every time make if ran.  However,  I also want it to say nothing is to be done if it is the only things running.

Comment: It is just printing them to the screen.  like echo "@N: sldjfldjsl"

Comment: Do you mean that the stuff with the `@N`s is not intended to be the value of `tvc` but is printed on the screen while `jpl-tcs.sh` is run? Or do you get that garbled output when printing `$(tvc)` by some other command you are not showing us?

Comment: if I run `jpl-tcs.sh` I get the formatted output above.  If i run the same command in Make with `tvc:=$(shell jpl-tcs.sh ...)` and `$(info $(tvc)) then I get the garbed output where the newline characters are omitted.  I want it to display like it does in the shell but when I call it in make.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
sed 's/ @N:/\n@N:/g' file
```

or, if the list is in a shell variable:

```
sed 's/ @N:/\n@N:/g' <<< "$list"
```

If the list is in a `make` variable, you could use something pretty similar in a recipe:

```
show_tvc:
    printf "%s\n" "$(tvc)" | sed 's/ @N:/\n@N:/g'
```

But the simplest solution is probably to send the shell command"s output to the terminal directly:

```
$(shell jpl-tcs.sh --check_tool_versions --pcf $(PCF) 1>&2)
```

Comment: I am running this command                                                                        `tvc := $(shell jpl-tcs.sh --check_tool_versions --pcf $(PCF))`

Comment: I can't run it in a recipe.  I need to run this before.  I could not get sed to work.  It does not make a file.  I am sorry for the confusion but I don't really know sed very well.

Comment: @Sabersimon: My bad. I was using a bashism in a Makefile, which is not possible since `make` uses `sh`, not `bash`. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Sabersimon: I really don't understand what your requirements are, so I'm probably not getting what you want. Why do you want to create a file? Or, to put it another way, if you want to create a file, why don't you create a file in the first place from the output of `jpl-tcs.sh`, which would avoid all the problems you have with losing newlines?

Comment: @Sabersimon: Try this: `$(shell jpl-tcs.sh --check_tool_versions --pcf $(PCF) 1>&2)`